# Python / Selenium looping problem with 'for'

Tags: python-3.x

im trying to loop this code with "for" but it gives a error. Can you help me to solve it, thank you.

**Error Code:**

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

**Source Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile("C:/Users/Baran/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/oy6k3nay.yarrak")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('http://www.ipsorgu.com/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

**What i tried:**

```
     .
       .
       .
       .
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe")
        #################################################################
        for i in range(10):
        ###################################################################
        driver.get('http://www.ipsorgu.com/')
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because every thing in a `for` loop has to be indented. So you final code could look like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe")
profile = FirefoxProfile("C:/Users/Baran/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/oy6k3nay.yarrak")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, executable_path="C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe")

for i in range(10):
   driver.get('http://www.ipsorgu.com/')

time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Oh yes, it's worked now. I can't believe i just wasted 1 hours just because of this. Thank you so much!